# Prove that if $A \cap C \subseteq B \cap C$ and $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$ then $A \subseteq B$

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble figuring out what to do in this problem.

I know that if $A \subseteq B$ then $A \cup B = B$ and $A \cap B = A$, but I can't wrap my head around on what to do with the given information to get my result.

Comment: Suppose $\alpha\in A $ but $\alpha \notin B$. Derive a contradiction.

Comment: Recall that to show that $A\subseteq B$, we can let $a$ be an arbitrary element of $A$ and show that $a\in B$. To do this, you can try taking cases based on whether $a\in C$ or $a\notin C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a \in A$ but $a \notin B$:

$a \in A \cup C \subset B \cup C \implies a \in C$.

Hence, $a \in A \cap C \subset B \cap C \subset B$, contradiction. So $a \in B$.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to doing these sorts of simple set theory problems, I find it is most useful to think explicitly about the few ways these mathematical objects can be *constructed* and *destructed*.

When it comes to subsets, we can only really construct and destruct by talking about element membership.

To construct proof of $A\subseteq B$, we need to show that $x\in A \implies x \in B$. That is going to be an inevitability (so long as we opt for a direct/constructive proof). Since this is the case, let us suppose that we have some particular element $x\in A$. Our goal now is just to prove that $x\in B$ using the other information at hand.

Now, the only way we can destruct the other two subset statements we have is to break them down as follows:
$A\cap C \subseteq B \cap C$ destructs to $x\in A\cap C \implies x \in B \cap C$ -- I'll call this statement (1).
Similarly, $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$ destructs to $x\in A\cup C \implies x\in B \cup C$, which I will call statement (2).
Since we assumed that $x\in A$, we can construct $x\in A\lor x\in C$ and hence $x\in A\cup C$, and hence invoke statement (2) to conclude that $x\in B\cup C$.

Then since we have $x\in B\cup C$, we can destruct this to $x\in B\lor x\in C$, and then we must consider two cases.

In the first case, $x\in B$.
Then we have shown that $x\in A \implies x\in B$ and hence $A\subseteq B$ as required, so we're done with this case!

In the second case, $x\in C$. But we already know that $x\in A$, so then we can construct $x\in A\land x\in C$ and hence $x\in A\cap C$. But then by statement (1) from earlier, this gives us that $x\in B\cap C$. This destructs to $x\in B \land x \in C$. So we have shown that $x\in A \implies x\in B$ as required, and we're done with this case too!

It's all about the constructors and destructors.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that for any sets $X, C$ you have
$$
X = ((X \cup C) \setminus C) \cup (X \cap C).
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1.** Suppose that $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$. Suppose the inclusion $A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C$ is valid. Note that each of the statements below implies the next.

- $(x\in A)$ and $(x\notin C)$ and $(A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C)$
- $(x\in A)$ and $(x\notin C)$ and $((x\in A\cup C)\implies (x\in B\cup C))$
- $(x\in A)$ and $(x\notin C)$ and $((x\in A )\mbox{ or } (x\in C))\implies ((x\in B)\mbox{ or }  (x\in C))$
- $(x\in A)$ and $(x\notin C)$ and $(x\in A)\implies (x\in B)$
- $x\in A$, $x\notin C$ and $A\subseteq B$

**Case 2.** Suppose that $x\in A$ and $x\in C$. Suppose the inclusion $A\cap C\subseteq B\cap C$ is valid. Note that each of the statements below implies the next.

- $(x\in A)$ and $(x\in C)$ and $(A\cap C\subseteq B\cap C)$
- $(x\in A)$ and $(x\in C)$ and $((x\in A\cap C)\implies (x\in B\cap C))$
- $(x\in A)$ and $(x\in C)$ and $((x\in A )\mbox{ and } (x\in C))\implies ((x\in B)\mbox{ and }  (x\in C))$
- $(x\in A)$ and $(x\in C)$ and $(x\in A)\implies (x\in B)$
- $x\in A$, $x\in C$ and $A\subseteq B$